# People are asking me questions. Do my answers matter?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

After I left the first tutorial area, I got asked three questions about what I valued, what I wanted, and what I was afraid of.

I said I valued friendship, I wanted to broaden my horizons, and I was afraid of being indecisive.

Do these answers matter? Do they make any significant changes to the game?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you answer wrong you get flung off the bridge

Comment: I wouldn't sweat this, honestly.  The differences are only really noticeable if you get big into maximizing every last stat there is in the game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, these answers will affect how fast your character will gain levels during the game.  The three different results possible are:

- Gaining levels at an average / standard rate throughout the game
- Gaining levels quickly early in the game, and then slower later in the game
- Gaining levels slower early in the game, and then quickly later in the game

The result depends on how you answer.  Based on your answers, you'll gain levels at an average speed throughout the game.  There's a more detailed chart [here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts/Awakening#Third_Platform).

Comment: You can also see more info at [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/516587-kingdom-hearts/faqs/19614). Note that if you gain levels slower in the beginning, you will need less experience to get to level 100 than the others.